# Delay reference to non-nested type based on static condition without compile error?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, template-meta-programming, conditional-compilation

Consider a header file whose contents are either

```
namespace foo
{
    static bool const exists = false;
}
```

or

```
namespace foo
{
    static bool const exists = true;
    typedef some_other_possibly_incomplete_type my_type;
}
```

(Assume this header file is given to me as-is and cannot be changed.)

Now consider this typedef:

```
typedef get_my_type_or_default<foo::exists, void>::type my_type_or_default;
```

The goal is to have `my_type_or_default` evaluate to `foo::my_type` if `foo::exists`, or `void` otherwise.

Is it possible to define `get_my_type_or_default` in a way that makes this work, or is this impossible? If this is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: @dyp: I can't modify the header, so if you can do that without modifying the header then sure. Otherwise no.

Comment: @dyp: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant. That's a good point. The problem is the typedef is not necessarily a complete type, even though I made the mistake of making it so in my example (edit: I fixed it to show what I mean).

Comment: @dyp: Well I don't know what its name might be, so I wouldn't know how to refer to it.

Comment: @dyp: Ahh! That's a brilliant answer, please post it!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using weird name lookup tricks, unfortunately polluting the global namespace :(

```
namespace foo
{
    //static bool const exists = true; // we don't need this
    struct some_other_possibly_incomplete_type;
    //typedef some_other_possibly_incomplete_type my_type;
}

using my_type = void;
namespace foo
{
    using this_one_surely_exists = my_type; // either foo::my_type or ::my_type
}


#include <iostream>
template<class T>
void print_type()
{ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    using gey_my_type_or_default = foo::this_one_surely_exists;
    print_type<gey_my_type_or_default>();
}
```

Comment: I think you can even prevent pollution of the global namespace -- use `using foo;` inside some other `detail` namespace, and define `my_type` to be `void` inside `detail`. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad If you mean `using namespace foo;`, then I don't think that will work: using-directives behave weirdly, they introduce the names in the smallest enclosing scope that contains the current and the referred namespace (which will be either `foo` or the global namespace).

Comment: Oh wow, that's really bizarre, I didn't realize that. :( bummer.